# Showing Function is Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \backslash \{2\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by $f(x) = \frac{2x^2+x-10}{3x-6}$.

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}{f(x)} & \text{if } x \neq 2 \\ 3 &\text{if } x = 2  \end{cases}$$

Prove that $g$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Workings:

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta =$ ______

Then in $|x-2| < \delta$, we have

$|g(x) - g(c)| = \left|\frac{2x^2+x-10}{3x-6} - 3\right|$

$=  \left|\frac{2x+5}{3} - 3\right|$

$= \left|\frac{2x+5}{3} - \frac{9}{3}\right|$

$= \left|\frac{2x-4}{3}\right|$

$= \frac{2}{3}\left|x-2\right|$

$< \frac{2}{3}\delta$

Now I'm not too sure what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pick $0<\delta < \frac{3}{2} \epsilon$. Then $\frac{2}{3} \delta < \epsilon$. By the way you show $g$ is continuous at $2$. But of course showing continuity at other points is easy - away from $2$, $g$ is the quotient of two continuous functions, and the denominator is not zero.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is shown that $g$ is continuous at $2$.  (Provided you choose $\delta = \frac{3}{2} \epsilon$.)

Since $g$ can be written as a rational function, it is continuous everywhere the denominator is non-zero. This is because if two functions are continuous at a point, then their ratio is continuous provided the denominator is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to calculate the 2 limits :
$$l_1 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2;  x > 2} g(x) \text{ and } l_2 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2;  x < 2} g(x)$$
and show that $l_1 = l_2 = g(2) = 3$. But $$l_1 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2;  x > 2} g(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2;  x > 2} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2;  x > 2} \frac{2x^2 + x - 10}{3x-6} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2;  x > 2} \frac{(2x^2 + x - 10)'}{(3x-6)'} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2;  x > 2} \frac{4x+1}{3} = 3$$ (using L'Hopital's rule). And similarly $l_2 = 3$. So the function is continuous.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use L'Hopital's Rule.